# Solr substring search yields all indexed results

Tags: solr

To do a substring search, I have added a new fieldType - "Text" with NgramFilter.

It works fine perfectly but downside is this problem

Example

```
name = ['Apple','Samy','And','a']
```

When I do a search `name:a`, then all the above items gets pulled up. Even when search changes to "App". All the above items are pulled. How can I fix this issue?

```xml
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="100" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

[image]

Comment: Are all the values indexed for the same document (it's not clear from your description)? What does analysis for the field show? (under /admin, select the core and analysis)

Comment: you mean to get it from the admin folder or admin console...?

Comment: Through the web interface. It'll allow you to see exactly what Solr does with the indexed value and your query value.

Comment: I went to solr admin/analysis...Gave my field name "name" and few values..but unable to infer anything from it..When I search for "Apple", it fetches the 'a' value as well. The mingramsize=1, will index 'a' but why would it be fetched when "Apple" is searched...

Comment: @Mats: I have added analysis snapshot for you reference..

Comment: The list of tokens present in the ENGTF row is the result from the edgengramfilter. It contains all variants of the word apple, and will match any of them. If you supply a query value as well (apple), it will highlight the match. If you're attempting to debug why you get a hit, enter the values for what you index and what you search, and generate the analysis data. It'll tell you which tokens match, and what each step of the process does to your data.

Comment: @Mats:Thanks much for your inputs...I have added the new snapshot that shows whats being indexed and whats being searched...My requirement is when I search "a"...then I should get ['Apple','Samy','And','a'] but when I search for "Apple", I should get only "Apple"...how do I limit my search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the analysis, both the indexed value and the query value gets parsed through the EdgeNGramFilter - meaning that it will match anything that is a substring of anything else. Add a simpler filter for querying the field, and you should be good to go.

The example from the Wiki should be usable by just copying and pasting it:

```
<fieldType name="text_general_edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

My initial guess was that since you don't provide two alternative definitions, Solr will use the same chain for both. Your analysis output confirms that suspicion. Try adding a analyser with `type="query"` to have a specific chain for querying the field (you do not want EdgeNGram both places).

Comment: :I have something related to the same thing...When I do a q search ie;  text:'app'..it does not yield any result but 'name':'app' yields a result...Why would not text:'app' does not yield a result..

Comment: Again, use the analysis page to see what values gets generated when indexing and what analysis is performed when searching. That will tell you why there's no match between the entries.

Comment: Im searching for 'app' in query console which translates to q=app..not sure what would be the analysis field name/type for 'q' object...

Comment: You're searching the field 'text', so go to analysis, select 'text', enter 'apple' as the indexed value (if that's what your putting into the index) and 'app' as the query value, if that's what you're searching for. The resulting output is what Solr has done for that field both when inserting and querying, and if there's no match present (meaning same tokens on both sides), you'll have to tune your analysis chain.

Comment: I did that...When I enter "Text" and analyze it. "Apple" is stored as "Apple"..When I enter "Name"(stored as text) and analyze it "Apple" is stored as "a","ap","app","apple"

Comment: .. so maybe you don't have the same field definition for both fields?

Comment: When I do a q search, Doesn't it mean it will search for all indexed field rather than the "text" field alone?

Comment: It will search in the field(s) defined by `defaultSearchField`, in `qf` (for (e)dismax), in `df` or straight in the `q` parameter. If you use q= together with a field name, it searches in that field name. The format of the `q` parameter depends on which query parser you're using by default. `text:apple` searches for the value `apple` in a field named `text` (a field, not a `fieldType`). You'll have to read up on the wiki for more about this, it is rather basic usage of Solr.